# postfix reciving mails

Tags: server, email, postfix

I change from that:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, fantasy.cmtim.si
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
#        mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain
```

to that, that i can recive mails.

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, fantasy.cmtim.si
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
        mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain
```

Is this safe option, or is easy hackable?

I'm new to this, and I would really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

This change is *neither secure nor insecure*, in so much that it doesn't change 'hackability' or not.

However, you actually *won't* be receiving data correctly unless you set your `mydomain` configuration option in the PostFix configuration.

The first version you had, with the original items commented, should be sufficient to 'receive' mail at your domain.  The relevant line - `mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, fantasy.cmtim.si` - was not commented out so it should have worked without much additional configuration.